# Quick random shuffle function in plain C

Tags: c, function, random, shuffle

For years I've thought about this, but never managed to implement one. I'm talking about a quick, efficient C function that accepts an integer numeric value (e.g. 16 bit) in input and gives a completely different number of the same bit-size in output, but "takes into account" all the numbers that were already given, although not by using real memory, but by math magic. Sorry, English is not my native language, what I mean is that the function should map one-to-one randomly but without any duplicates.

Possible applications I imagined were for example one of those pixel-crossfade graphics routines where you replace the old pic on the screen with the new one, pixel by pixel. The coordinates should be chosen randomly, and once a pixel is replaced, it should not be addressed again (no duplicates). All of this naturally by a small, quick and efficient function math-based (it would be easy to implement this using memory, but it's not what I want).

Clearly a "bit-reverse" solution won't work because it won't look random. Even swapping e.g. bit 3 with bit 11, etc.. to create more "chaos", invert some bits, etc.. didn't really look good, so I'm looking for a pure mathematical, really random-looking, function, capable possibly of at least 16bit, and using as little memory as possible (no precomputed tables, as the first application I'd finally use it is on a micro-controller system to make an old-style game with public domain hardware and software).

Can you help please?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is basically a cyclic generator of the group corresponding to the number of pixels you want to crossfade. In the most general case, this is any coprime to the size of your group. By way of doing all calculations modulo your number of pixels, you get **the appearance** of randomness without this being actually random.

Let's say you have a domain of size 32 and start with a seed of 5. By constantly adding the coprime of 15, you would get the sequence of

> (5, 20, 3, 18, 1, 16, 31, 14, 29, 12, 27, 10, 25, 8, 23, 4,...)

This probably will seem random enough for your requirements.

Comment: +1: Sounds nice! Now how does the OP find a coprime of his domain size?

Comment: @AAT: According to [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) you can simply use `domain_size/2 - 1`.

Comment: @wildplasser: And `9 + 15 != 14` ;). Corrected the sequence.

Comment: I agree that's somewhat of a larger problem here, especially as the "randomness" starts to become obvious for to small coprimes. If 32-bit arithmetic is available, it might be best to choose one of the cryptographically valued (or used in PRNG) coprimes to the 32-bit domain, such as the ones used in Linear Congruential Generators or the classical Mersenne Twister.

Comment: Thanks for the edits all, my mental arithmetic isn't what it used to be :)

Comment: @Zeta: `(domain_size / 2) - 1` works for 32 (and I think other powers of 2) but it's not a general solution: for a trivial demonstration, if the domain size is 30 your formula would give a suggestion of 14, which is not coprime with 30 (common factor 2). I don't think your applying Bézout's identity correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to use an encryption.  Since encryption is reversible, every encryption is unique.  For 64 bit number use DES.  For 16 or 32 bit numbers, use [Hasty Pudding Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_Cipher).  You can also adapt Hasty Pudding for any desired range, not just powers of two.

Answer (score 0):

You sir are pretty much in need of a hash function. try for example a=(a*31)%0xffff;  for a poor one.

Answer (score 0):

The `rand()` function already does this. Although, instead of taking a number from input, it takes a stored value that was initialized by `srand()` and changed with each call to `rand()`.

You can either look at the implementation of `rand()` to get your function, or study more on [random number generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).

Here's a hint:

First, understand what is [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Now imagine the following sequence:

```
m = 13
a = 7
b = 0

s = 5     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 9     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 11    s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 12    s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 6     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 3     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 8     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 4     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 2     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 1     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 7     s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 10    s = (a*s + b) % m
s = 5     s = (a*s + b) % m
```

Note that in this case, I set `b=0` to more easily find a sequence. Nevertheless, this example is not really great, but you get the gist. Given a good choice of `a` and `b` for a given `m`, you can get numbers that do kinda look random.

This way, all your function needs to do is `(a * argument + b) % m`.

Comment: I don't think it does, i.e. there may be two input values of srand() which will return the same output. Also, maybe it's wrong but I've read somewhere that srand() must only be called once in a program.

Comment: @user1570761, I am not suggesting using `rand`. I am saying your function is similar to how `rand` works. That is, you can most probably find an implementation of rand online and you can adapt it to your program, i.e. make it apply its algorithm on the input argument rather than its global variable.

Comment: Also, with different values in `srand`, you will start at a different location in the cycle of numbers. Since that cycle covers all numbers (mine doesn't, but real `rand()` does) and doesn't repeat for any number, you can't get the same value for two different inputs.